# Rake task not working with postgresql and sinatra-activerecord

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake

I was trying to setup facebook app locally, using ruby and sinatra, in Kubuntu 12.04.
I have included following gems in my gemfile. I have postgresql installed in my system and I am able to run the postgresql command line and run basic commands as createdb, create table etc.

```
gem "sinatra"
gem "koala"
gem "json", "1.5.5"
gem "httparty"
gem "thin"
gem "rack", "1.3.10"
gem "pg"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
```

And in my app.rb file added these files,

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require "koala"
require "./config/environment" #database configuration
```

Running

```
rake -T
```

in my terminal gives me the following error.

```
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:39:in `database_file='
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1033:in `set'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:50:in `registered'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1317:in `block in register'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1315:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1315:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1648:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1688:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:76:in `<module:Sinatra>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nitin/facebook_app/guarded-gorge-3234/app.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nitin/facebook_app/guarded-gorge-3234/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
```

Could any one please help. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a bad character in the config/environment file. Are you able to post what's in it? Specifically line 2, character 1.

Comment: @iain My environment.rb file: #The environment variable DATABASE_URL should be in the following format:
# => postgres://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/path
configure :production, :development do
 db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/mydb')
 
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
   :host     => db.host,
   :username => db.user,
   :password => db.password,
   :database => db.path[1..-1],
   :encoding => 'utf8'
 )
end

Comment: code at [link](http://codetidy.com/5964/). Thank you.

Comment: Looking at [the source for sinatra-activerecord](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/blob/v1.2.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb#L50) the problem isn't with what I asked for (that looks alright, by the way) but with `config/database.yml`. Are you able to post that?

Answer (score 0):

As @iain mentioned, this is due to a parse error in your config/database.yml file.
Check that it is valid syntax, and replace any tabs with spaces.